# Using PyQt4.QtWebKit on a Debian server

Tags: python, debian, pyqt4, qtwebkit, vnc-server

I'm having a problem using PyQT4 on a Debian server. My script works fine on an Ubuntu Desktop machine, and I now want to deploy it on a server.

Knowing it needed an X server, I launched one doing

```
vncserver --display 800x600 :4242
```

I then exported the display :

```
export DISPLAY=:4242
```

But my program keeps returning the error

> cannot connect to X server :4242

Any idea ?

Comment: Did you try to `strace python your_script.py` to see how it tries to connect ?

Comment: Yes, it seems to point out a "No protocol specified" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not --display, it's -geometry.

I would guess you don't have the rights to connect to the vncserver. It was already running, wasn't it ?
Try running another instance.

Comment: I was lauchning a brand new one, so it's not about rights. But your syntax correction saved me !

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using vncserver, you could use (at least on Debian) 
xvfb - Virtual Framebuffer 'fake' X server.

After installing this package simply run:

```
$ xvfb-run python your_script.py
```